# What is the procedure to start Safari browser?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium2, selenium-webdriver, safaridriver

I'm new & started working on selenium from last month. 
I was successfully running script on FF & chrome. 
but when I started to run same script on Win safari It gives browser initilization error.
what should I do for launching SafariDriver on Windows?

Comment: Whay is the error message you're getting?

Comment: Question yourself if you want to support the Windows version of Safari, it has been discontinued since 2013. Better use a Mac version or on something like saucelabs or testingbot cloud services. https://saucelabs.com/

Comment: Yes, but I have to work with windows Safari.
I have a client  which has given win-safari support.

Comment: I think you should advice them to reconsider that for two reasons. One you will run into issues with testing, because it is unsupported. Second using Win-Safari version is very insecure, no sane IT department should support it. There is not a significant group of actual users for Win-Safari. So I see no reason to waste time on it, but if you must goodluck :) Also testing Safari on Windows is not a replacement for testing it on a Mac, because it is so old it does not compare at all. Keep this things in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Launching Safari browser is very easy, just you have to add safariDriver jar in your Windows Safari browser. Check after installation whether this icon is displayed or not?

[image]

If Yes then it will work.
Steps-
**Requirements:**
Safari Browser installed
Selenium WebDriver
Now we have to install SafariDriver extension with below steps.
Manually install the latest Safari extension:

Download [Safari Driver jar from here.](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-safari-driver/2.43.1/selenium-safari-driver-2.43.1.jar)
Rename the file to a `.zip` file instead of a `.jar` file – Unzip it (just double click on it to do so).
In Folder, go to `../selenium-safari-driver-2.43.1/org/openqa/selenium/safari`.
Double click “`SafariDriver.safariextz`” or simple drag this file in browser.

```
WebDriver driver = new SafariDriver();
driver.get("Url");
```